# set content in dynamically loaded tinyMCE editor

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have webpage (index.pl), in it's **div** (id = 'right') i have dynamically loaded a page(editor.pl) containing  **textarea**.To change this textarea as **TinyMce editor** I have dyanamically loaded a js file (include_tiny_mce.js) which has tinyMce.init() function as below :

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'editor.pl',
    success:function(msg){
    $("#right").html(msg);
    $("head").append("<script src='/include_tiny_mce.js'></script><script src='/scripts.js'></script>");

    },
```

Now all this is working fine and all textareas are changed to tinyMce but when I am using 
`tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("hello world");`
 from a js file (script.js, already included in index.pl) to set content in tinyMce it is not showing the content.
Anyone can tell me the solution for this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable activeEditor gets set when you first "activate/use" it (like clicking into it).
In case you are using only one single editor you may use `tinymce.editors[0]` :

```
tinymce.editors[0].setContent("hello world");
```

In all other cases use the tinymce instance object this way

```
tinymce.get('right').setContent("hello world");
```

Comment: if using several tinymce on one page and using indexed ids to populate from Jquery
(e.g. id='my_txt[0]' ) then the first example works on all, but the second  misses the '0' (zero) item

Comment: delete my comment - these both work well for TinyMCE4